# rsyslog logging asa data to multiple files

Tags: rsyslog

I setup rsyslog to log asa data to /var/log/asa/asa.log.  That worked fine.  But it's also logging asa details to /var/log/messages.  I only want it to go to /var/log/asa/asa.log/.

Here is the rsyslog configuration:

```
[root@util01 etc]# grep -v "^#" rsyslog.conf  | grep -v "^$"
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 *
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local6.*                                                /var/log/asa/asa.log
daemon.*                                                /var/log/bc/bc.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

Any idea how I can only capture the data in the asa file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a message is compared with each of the filter lines in the order you have given in the config file. So your message probably matches the selector `*.info...` before it then goes on to also match `local6.*...`.  It is therefore put in both of the files.

The command to stop further processing of a message is `stop`, instead of a filename.

Putting these two points together you need to re-organise your config file so that the lines

```
local6.*                /var/log/asa/asa.log
local6.*                stop
```

appear before the line with `/var/log/messages`.  You can also take advantage of a third point, namely that `&` can be used to repeat the selector of the previous line, and so instead write:

```
local6.*                /var/log/asa/asa.log
&                       stop
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will try that tonight.

Comment: Works, Saved me a ton of looking.